# WordPress: Fix oEmbed and <--/wp:paragraph--> in shortcode?

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, embed, oembed

I have created shortcode that will show to non-logged users (non-subscribers) part of text, or 100 characters.
And for logged in users (subscribers) it will show full content.

```
function subscriber_only( $atts, $content = null ) {
if(is_user_logged_in()){
  echo get_the_content();
} else {
$more = '
<p>No Access.</p>
';
echo force_balance_tags( html_entity_decode( wp_trim_words( htmlentities( get_the_content() ), 100, $more ) ) );
}
}

add_shortcode('subscriber_only', 'subscriber_only');
```

Everything works great, except YouTube links won't show as an iframe (oEmbed) and  <--/wp:paragraph-->  is breaking `<p>No Access.</p>` - this does not show on some posts.
How do I make oEmbed works and solve <--/wp:paragraph--> problem ?

Comment: Please post some screenshots as well to let us see what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Show a working example code as well.

Comment: Post what type of data are you feeding inside the contents. Also I don't see anything related to oEmbed. oEmbed data must be present inside your contents. Make sure to show full contents data in it's full state and your desired state as well.